# How to drop unused labels from a memisc:data.set in R?

Tags: r

I want to drop **all unsued labels** from a `data.set`.

Let's assume this example `data.set` (which is class from the [`memisc`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/memisc/) package).

```
library(memisc)
d <- data.set(a = sample(1:10), b=rep(c(14,72),5))
labels(d$b) <- c('First' = 14, 'no-use' = 33, 'Second' = 72)
```

The resulting `data.set`:

```
Data set with 10 observations and 2 variables

    a      b
 1  4  First
 2  1 Second
 3  9  First
 4  8 Second
 5  7  First
 6 10 Second
 7  5  First
 8  3 Second
 9  2  First
10  6 Second
```

You see that for `b` only two values used but it has three labels.

```
> labels(d$b)

 Values and labels:

   14 'First' 
   33 'no-use'
   72 'Second'
```

How can I drop the unused label (`33`) from there? The point is **all unsued labels** should be droped and I don't know which one is unused. I would know how to remove `33` explicite. But that is not the goal.

I know from the basic-R `data.frame` the function `droplevels()`. Would be nice to have something like `droplabels()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't very compact, but you could use the following

```
labels(d$b) <- labels(d$b)[seq_len(length(unique(d$b)))]
```

**update**

Your question states you want to drop '72' when it looks like you want to drop '33'.  Regardless, the following function will drop any unused labels

```
labels(d$b) <- labels(d$b)[labels(d$b)@values %in% unique(d$b)]
```

The following will drop all unused labels for all elements of a list

```
for (i in seq_along(d)) {
  if(!is.null(labels(d[[i]]))) {
    labels(d[[i]]) <- labels(d[[i]])[labels(d[[i]])@values %in% unique(d[[i]])]
   }
}
```

Comment: This only works when the unused lables are at the end of the label-list. I modified my question to cover that use-case.

Comment: @buhtz answer updated to drop unused labels regardless of position